# make user input loop variables in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script which is run as:

```
>> bash test.sh < 0 0
```

Inside test.sh

```
read $sni
read $snf

echo 'Run between '$sni' and '$snf
for i in {sni..snf}
do

done
```

But I get the following error:

```
test.sh: line 14: [: {sni..snf}: integer expression expected
test.sh: line 19: [: {sni..snf}: integer expression expected
```

How to I make the loop variable integers? Thanks.

Comment: Also, you should be using `read sni`, because you *don't* want variable interpolation there.

Comment: @jpaugh ad 1) Sadly, you can't. If you want to use variables here you have to use `seq` (with `bash` anyway).

Comment: Ouch! Wow! You're right.

Comment: @jpaugh We can pretend that you were suggesting to use `ksh`, which is cleverererer than `bash` and there it works :-)

Comment: Haha. Unfortunately, I wasn't that bright. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to sum up the various input and in case you want to stick with your `for` syntax.

```
read $sni
```

This is indirection. You are not reading into the variable `${sni}` but into the variable whose name is held by `${sni}`, e.g.:

```
$ foo=bar
$ read $foo <<< "quux"
$ echo "${foo}"
bar
$ echo "${bar}"
quux
```

So this should be

```
read sni
```

instead. And about ...

```
for i in {sni..snf}
```

... this does not work because you are not treating your variables as variables here.
If you use `ksh`  then you can do

```
for i in {${sni}..${snf}}; do
    ...
done
```

but `bash` is not so clever in which case you want to use

```
for i in $(seq ${sni} ${snf}); do
    ...
done
```

So the whole thing should look more like:

```
#!/bin/sh

read sni
read snf

echo "Run between '${sni}' and '${snf}'"
for i in $(seq ${sni} ${snf}); do
        echo "i=$i"
done
```

Example:

```
$ printf "1\n4\n" | ./t.sh
Run between '1' and '4'
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
for (( i=$sni ; i<=$snf ; i++ ))
```

From the bash help

```
(( ... )): (( expression ))
    Evaluate arithmetic expression.

    The EXPRESSION is evaluated according to the rules for arithmetic
    evaluation.  Equivalent to "let EXPRESSION".

    Exit Status:
    Returns 1 if EXPRESSION evaluates to 0; returns 0 otherwise.
```

Also you can pass variables to the shell script as command arguments.

```
bash test.sh 1 2
```

The would be contained in the variables `$1` and `$2`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ ! $2 ]]
then
  echo test.sh SNI SNF
  exit
fi

echo "Run between $1 and $2"
seq $1 $2 | while read i
do
  # do stuff
done
```